# How can i access variables outside a for loop in perl

Tags: perl

I want to access `$hash_element->{'test_plan'}` and `$hash_element->{'build'}` outside the for loop

```
my $hash_element;
for $hash_element (@bats) {
    my $dbh = DBI->connect( $dsn, $BAT_DB_user, $BAT_DB_password );
    my ( @plan_id, @plan_run );
    @plan_id = $dbh->selectrow_array(
               "select id from plan where name='$hash_element->{'test_plan'}'");
}

$emailsubject = "BAT - " . $hash_element->{'test_plan'} . " on " . $hash_element->{'build'} . " done.";
```

Answer (score 8):

First, please learn how to use [placeholders and bind variables](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) in SQL.

Second, what values do you expect "outside the loop"?  You've gone through the entire list of `@bats`.  What do you think would be in there after that's all done?

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what exactly you want to do - there's no obvious value for a loop variable outside of its loop. Do you want to access the LAST element of @bats? FIRST element? Some element satisfying a particular condition?

For the last element, simply do:

```
my $hash_element_last;
for my $hash_element (@bats) {
    # whatever logic
    $hash_element_last = $hash_element;
}
my $emailsubject = "BAT - " . $hash_element_last->{'test_plan'};
```

For some other element, you also stash it inside of a separate value:

```
my $hash_element_remembered;
for my $hash_element (@bats) {
    # whatever logic
    # Use for the first element
    $hash_element_remembered = $hash_element unless defined $hash_element_remembered;
    # Use for the "special" element
    $hash_element_remembered = $hash_element if (some_special_logic)
}
my $emailsubject = "BAT - " . $hash_element_remembered->{'test_plan'};
```

Please note that for first/last, your can of course simply use `$bats[0]` and `$bats[-1]` without specially remembering the loop element inside the loop (assuming you don't want "the last element seen in the loop which may exit via `last` prior to finishing looping).